# Can I get Load percentage or estimated execution time for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I am writing a GUI admin application for my server using java Swing.

I thought it would be good to have some kind of loading bar or load percentage when the MySQL query is taking long to execute.

Is there anyway I can get an estimated execution time or load percentage for MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. MySQL can't predict the execution time before executing it.